DevExpress Popup disappears when orientation changes
I use a DevExpress Popup for .NET MAUI (DXPopup) and integrate it in XAML within a ContentView like this:
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto">
    
    <Image x:Name="BackgroundImage" Source="corn_cob.png" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFill" Margin="{OnPlatform Android='0, -40, 0, 0', Default='0'}"/>

    <dxco:DXPopup x:Name="popup"
          IsOpen="True"
          AllowScrim="True"
          CloseOnScrimTap="True"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          HeightRequest="300"
          WidthRequest="300"
          Margin="24"
          CornerRadius="16">

        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <pickerContent:CustomPopupContentView/>
        </VerticalStackLayout>

    </dxco:DXPopup>
</Grid>

First of all, it did not show up even if IsOpen is hardcoded set to true. So, I had to add in code-behind of that view:
public CalculateView()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ...

    popup.Show();
}

When I start the application it now shows the Popup.
In case I change the orientation from Portrait to Landscape, the Popup disappears and I don't know why?
I also have an overwrite of OnSizeAllocated(...) to change some sizes. There, I also tried to actiave it again and call .Show() again which did not help. I also tried with IsOpen = true again, but this also did not help.
protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
{
    base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);

    if (height < 0)
    {
        return;            
    }

    if (height > width)
    {
        BackgroundImage.HeightRequest = height * 0.7;
    }
    else
    {
        BackgroundImage.HeightRequest = height;
    }

    if (width > 0)
    {
        DistributionGrid.WidthRequest = width * 0.9;
    }

    CalculateScrollView.HeightRequest = height;

    popup.IsOpen = true;
    popup.Show();
}


How can I get this working so that the DXPopup is still visible when the screen orientation is changed and stays until I want to close it? Or how could I re-open it?
